# ApplicationContextAware ApplicationContext injection some times returns null

Tags: java, spring

Why i am getting context as null some times?
I have written Util class to get bean in Spring.It works fine in Server , but after few hours or days we got NPE. Then we realized that we are getting null context.
Following is the code

```
public class ApplicationUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext context;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    context = ac;
}

public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
        return context.getBean(beanName);
}
}
```

To avoid NPE we had written

```
 public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
    if (context != null) {
        return context.getBean(beanName);
    }
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dispatcher-servlet.xml");
    return context.getBean(beanName);
}
```

My question is why we are getting null even if we use ApplicationContextAware.Is this a Server issue ? or Bad programmatic Practice?

any  suggestions?

Comment: Bad programming imho. You shouldn't need such a bean. If the getter is called before the util is actually initialized by spring there is no context or it might have not be fully initialized. Avoid these beans and use dependency injection instead.